# Two apps cant be installed at the same time from google app store

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed 2 apps which is similar but different in content. I can install both apks locally. I have signed it with the same key.But once I publish it on Google play, I am not able to install both the apps but only either one of them. After downloading and trying to install it shows the error "Cant install, try again later".

links to the app 
[dailyin1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.dailyIn.upsc)
[dailyin2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.dailyIn.analytical)

Answer (score 0):

Did you give them different package names?  i.e:

```
package com.mycompany.dailyin1;
package com.mycompany.dailyin2;
```

Comment: the package names are different `io.dailyIn.upsc` and 'io.dailyIn.analytical'.  Can be seen in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situations before.

Possible scenarios:

1.You didn't change `applicationId` in **app/gradle.build**.

**Solution:** simply change `applicationId`.

2.You have a defined a provider for facebook(or something similar) in AndroidManifest.xml like `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXX.`

**Solution:** Comment out that provider for testing or add different ids for providers for different build variants.

Comment: I am building the app on ionic . It only has a config.xml   where id of the app is put. io.dailyIn.upsc and `io.dailyIn.analytical` are put there are app ids. There is a `build.gradle` file but there are no `applicationId` there.

Comment: @raj it is very sad, you must have added those lines in your question and tags too to properly answer the question. my answer holds for the context you provided in the question